# MySql trigger fires two times

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER catalog_product_entity_decimal_update AFTER UPDATE ON catalog_product_entity_decimal
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    -- blah blah blah
    END
```

Trigger make lot of operations but it doesn't matter :) the real problem is that when I make update from hand by code:

```
UPDATE `grene2`.`catalog_product_entity_decimal` SET `value`='82.0000' WHERE `entity_id`='276259';
```

It fires 2 times (I see it by profiling), BUT if I change same field by MySql Workbench it fires only one time. MySql Workbench creates such query:

```
`UPDATE `grene2`.`catalog_product_entity_decimal` SET `value`='81.0000' WHERE `value_id`='132371'`;
```

value_id is `PRIMARY` index, `entity_id` not probably there is a problem but WHY? And how to fix it?

Comment: Any chance you've got two entity_id equal to 276259 ?

Comment: Heh, I'm sooo stupid :) Thanks you have absolutely right :)